# How do I rewrite this query using CTE in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

My query is as listed below

```
UPDATE tname 
SET cname1 = TRIM(TRAILING 'xxx' from l_name), 
    cname2 = f_name, 
    cname3 = TRIM(TRAILING 'xxx' from l_name)  
where tname.last_name ilike '%xxxyyy%' and cid in (zzzz);
```

How do I rewrite this using CTE in Postgres? So that I don't repeat using trim function twice in my query?

Comment: It's a simple update, you don't need to use CTE for that.

Comment: Why do you want to store the same value in two columns? Looks like a poor table design.

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
with cte as
(
  select TRIM(TRAILING 'xxx' from l_name) as n1,
f_name
from tname where tname.last_name like '%xxxyyy%' and cid in (zzzz)
) update tname 
 set cname1=n1,
cname2=cte.f_name,
cname3=n1 
from cte       
  where t1.f_name=cte.f_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about it.  But if you have a primary key, you can use:

```
UPDATE tname 
    SET cname1 = tt.trimmed_l_name, 
        cname2 = tname.f_name, 
        cname3 = tt.trimmed_l_name 
FROM (SELECT tn.*, TRIM(TRAILING 'xxx' FROM l_name) as trimmed_l_name
      FROM tname tn 
     ) tt
     ON tname.pk = tn.pk
WHERE tname.last_name ilike '%xxxyyy%' and tname.cid in (zzzz);
```